# List all vendors which do not have active contracts in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Assuming the following stucture
table contract: contract_id, status_id, vendor_id
table status: active (status_id = 1), inactive (status_id = 2), deleted (status_id=3)
table vendor: vendor_id, vendor_name

How can I list only vendors with their contracts, all of them either inactive or deleted?
so if there is at least one contract for specific vendor which is active, this vendor and all of his contracts should be omitted

EDIT:
sample schema
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01f4c/5

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the closest I had was SELECT distinct status_id, name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + CAST(vendor_id as varchar)
           FROM contract b 
           WHERE b.status_id = a.status_id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM contract a
GROUP BY status_id;

Comment: So it sounds like your desired result set is the set of all the vendors with their contracts where the vendor id is not in the set of all the vendors who have an active contract.

Comment: My desired result is set of vendors who do not have contracts with status = 1. With my last try it is still manual comparing three lists. Unfortunately, SQL is not my preferred language.

Comment: You might get more help if you create the database structure on sqlfiddle.com and populate it with some data.

Comment: Here is it, also update post http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01f4c/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking something like this might fit the bill. Qry1 is the set of all contracts with the relevant vendor and status columns. Qry2 returns the set of all vendors with no active contracts. The final query returns everything from Qry1 where the vendor is not in Qry2.

```
With Qry1 As (
    Select      Vendor.VendorId, 
                Vendor.VendorName, 
                Contract.ContractId, 
                Contract.ContractName, 
                Status.StatusName
    From        Vendor
    Inner Join  Contract
    On          Vendor.VendorId = Contract.VendorId
    Inner Join  Status
    On          Contract.StatusId = Status.StatusId
),
Qry2 As (
    Select Distinct VendorId
    From        Qry1
    Where       StatusName = 'Active'
)
Select      Qry1.*
From        Qry1
Where Not Exists (
    Select      Qry2.VendorId
    From        Qry2
    Where       Qry2.VendorId = Qry1.VendorId
)
```

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd like to point out that in your question, you state "...inactive or deleted", which would mean two statuses(2,3), yet in your last comment, you specify where status = 1, which is active. This is very confusing. However, based on your last comment, which I will treat as the most up to date requirements, I believe the below query will get what you want.

EDIT: I believe I just figured out what you meant. There's some ambiguity in the way you wrote your last comment. Adjusted the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM vendors v
     LEFT JOIN contract c ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
WHERE c.STATUS in (2,3)
      AND c.vendor_id IS NULL
```

Comment: OP wants to _exclude_ all vendors with one or more active contracts.

Comment: _exclude_ as in _not in_ or _not exists_. Your query does not give the correct results either way.

Comment: Don't know how you arrived at that. He states: "How can I list only vendors with their contracts, all of them either inactive or deleted?" That looks pretty clear to me.